# jquery pop-up working in jsFiddle but not on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBKaZ/352/) with a pop-up box, and I'm trying to implement in on my site.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>Tell me a story</p>
    <textarea id="name"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="button" id="open" value="Open Dialog" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: { 
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
       },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#open").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Although it works on jsfiddle, on my site the div appears inside the page and not as a pop-up (just like I wouldn't have Jquery-UI).

My site has Jquery-2.0.2 and jQuery-ui-1.0.3, which according to jsfiddle it should work.

Any tips of what I might be missing?

Comment: Try putting the javascript code in your document ready function. And make sure you have included jQuery + jQuery UI

Comment: Have you include jQuery UI CSS?

Comment: Just curious have you included `jquery-ui.css`?

Comment: Please let us know what all you have included?

Comment: no, I don't have jquery-ui.css, as I didn't see it in jsfiddle, I'll google and test it now

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Man you need to include it. In fiddle demo it is added automatically on selection of jquery package from dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this script and css in your head tag

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>                       
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

It will link jQuery js file, jQuery UI API js file, and jQuery UI CSS file.

You can refer demo [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Thank you, I added them all but its still not working

Comment: Check this fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/tSx4C/1/ you can check external resources section to have a look at included files. Its working fine over here.

Comment: Oh yeah, its working, I had a typo :D Thank you, I knew jsfiddle wraps the code in appropriate tags but didn't know about the .css

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle is configured to wrap the code in the `onload` event. So if you run this on your site, you need to manually add the DOM ready wrapper (or place the code right before the `</body>`). Without this, your code runs before the elements are rendered, and subsequently the dialog is not transformed into a dialog by jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: { 
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
           },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#open").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: I added the your change and its still the same